# Determining if a pair of functions are linearly independent - need help

Tags: calculus

I have to determine if this pair of functions are linearly independent. The pair of functions is:

{$e^{\lambda_1 x}$, $e^{\lambda_2 x}$}, $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$

So I have set it out as follows:

$ae^{\lambda_1 x}+be^{\lambda_2 x}=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are non-zero.

If I set $x=0$ then this implies $a+b=0$

Then if I set $x=1$ this implies $a(e^{\lambda_1 x}-e^{\lambda_2 x})=0$ given that $a=-b$ from $x=0$. Now I am not sure where to go from here? What does this show?

Comment: Plug $x=1$ into $e^{\lambda_1x}-e^{\lambda_2x}=0$ to prove that $a=0$

Comment: Reduce from two nonzero unknowns $a,b$ to one by dividing out one of them.  Now the sum $a+b=0$ tells us what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually already showed it.  We know that $e^{\lambda_1}\neq e^{\lambda_2}$; so, if $a(e^{\lambda_1}-e^{\lambda_2})=0$, then necessarily $a=0$.  Then, since $a+b=0$, it must be the case that $b=0$ as well.

Comment: Of course, missed that even though it was right in front of me!

Answer (score 1):

Dividing both sides by $(e^{\lambda_1 x}-e^{\lambda_2 x})$ you get $a=0$, hence by the first equation $b=0$, and the formula $ae^{\lambda_1 x}+be^{\lambda_2 x}=0$ has no non-zero solution, so the functions are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, so here is a non-answer. Suppose that $ae^{\lambda_1 x}+be^{\lambda_2 x}$ is identically $0$.  You have observed that $a+b=0$.

Differentiate, and set $x=0$. We get $\lambda_1 a+\lambda_2 b=0$.  Since $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$, we get that $a=b=0$.